# undefined reference to `timer_getoverrun' fixed by passing -lrt to gcc. But why?

Tags: linux, gcc, timer, linker-errors

I was experimenting with a few timer functions and ended up with the above linker error. Someone on the net suggested to pass -lrt to gcc and it worked! What is '-lrt' and how did it help to overcome this error?

I looked into gcc --help but couldn't find these options and the man page of gcc ( which is too huge ) also dint give much insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds the rt library to the linker (see [librt](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_1.1.0/LSB_1.1.0/gLSB/app-librt.html)) which amongst other things defines `timer_getoverrun`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the gcc man page, because it's not an option. It's a library ( `-l` stands for `library`, this is the way, libs are passed to the linker)

`rt` is a time library. `timer_getoverrun` is just defined there.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused that 'r' and 't'are some kinda gcc options :)

Answer (score 1):

The `timer_getoverrun()` function is implemented in librt.so. From the `timer_getoverrun(2)` man page:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>    ...
>
>    Link with -lrt.
> ```